# Distinguish C-u <key> from C-u 4 <key>

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-argument

I know that <kbd>C-u</kbd> sends the prefix `4`. Is there any way to make <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd><key></kbd> a special case of a command, while still allowing <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>4</kbd> <kbd><key></kbd>?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sure.  Use the raw prefix argument instead:

```el
(defun my-prefix-test (arg)
  (interactive "P")
  (cond
   ((consp arg)   (message "Prefix argument"))
   ((numberp arg) (message "Numeric argument"))
   ((eq '- arg)   (message "Negative argument"))
   ((not arg)     (message "No argument"))))
```

As you can see, `current-prefix-arg` can be a list, a number, `-` or `nil`.